# Integral $\int _{0}^{\pi /2}x\cos (8x)\ln \tan x \, \text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Inspired by [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218787/how-can-we-show-that-int-0-pi-2x-cos8x-ln-left1-tan-x-over-1-tan-x-r), can I easily prove the result below?

$$\int _{0}^{\pi /2}x\cos (8x)\ln \tan x \, \text{d}x=\frac{13}{36}$$

The elementary antiderivative exists, but it seems masochist if one wants compute it.

Comment: have you tried parts with $u'(x)=\cos(8x)$ and $v(x)=x \log(\tan(x))$? the resulting integrals aren't looking too bad

Comment: the "annoying" part which is left after the first ipb namley the term with the remaining $x$ can be further simplified by another ipb (since $\sin(4 x)/\sin(x)$ has a very pleasent antiderivative) so this is definitly the way to go

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote, a CAS can find the antiderivative $$f(x)=\int x \cos(nx)\log (\tan (x))\,dx$$ and it is quite ugly (involving hypergeometric series with arguments $e^{4ix}$).

So, it is clear that, if $n$ is a multiple of $4$ , there will be a lot of simplifications for $$g(n)=\int_0^{\frac\pi 2} x \cos(nx)\log (\tan (x))\,dx$$ as shown below for the first ones.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & g(n) \\
 4 & \frac{3}{4} \\
 8 & \frac{13}{36} \\
 12 & \frac{211}{900} \\
 16 & \frac{7613}{44100} \\
 20 & \frac{270407}{1984500}
\end{array}
\right)$$ What is also interesting is that for other even values of $n$, the result is just a multiple of ${\pi^2}$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & g(n) \\
 2 & -\frac{\pi ^2}{8} \\
 6 & -\frac{\pi ^2}{24} \\
 10 & -\frac{\pi ^2}{40} \\
 14 & -\frac{\pi ^2}{56} \\
 18 & -\frac{\pi ^2}{72}
\end{array}
\right)$$ the denominator being just $4n$.

For sure, for these specific cases and in particular the one you posted, as @tired commented, integration by parts leads to "quite simple" result.

Comment: that different values of even $n$ behave so different is a nice observation! (+1)

Comment: @tired. Thanks ! Be sure I appreciate. I had fun with that (thinking about the monster a CAS gives for the antiderivative). What is nice is that, for odd values of $n$, the resulting expression of the integral is "quite" nice too.

Comment: what is fascinating too me that the terms with $pi^2$ have super regular pattern in their rational parts, whereas the others are very non regular (on first sight at least)

Comment: @tired. We obviously share the same ideas ! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \int x \cos(8x) \ln(\tan x) dx =$ $\displaystyle \frac{1}{576}(9\ln(\cos x)+72x\sin(8x)\ln(\tan x)+9\cos(8x)\ln(\tan x)-$ $\displaystyle 9\ln(\sin x)-144x\sin(2x)-48x\sin(6x)-90\cos(2x)-14\cos(6x)) + C$

Because of $\enspace\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi/2} (\cos x) (\tan x)^{8x \sin(8x) + \cos (8x)} = 1 \enspace$ and $\enspace\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(\tan x)^{\cos (8x)}}{\sin x} = 1$

we get $\enspace\displaystyle \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} x \cos(8x) \ln(\tan x) dx =\frac{2}{576}(90+14)=\frac{13}{36}$ .

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\cos\pars{8x}\ln\pars{\tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
> {13 \over 36}:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{equation}\bbx{%
\mbox{Note that}\ 
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!x\cos\pars{8x}\ln\pars{\tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
\left.\partiald{}{\nu}\bbox[#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\sin\pars{\nu x}\ln\pars{\tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x}}\,\right\vert_{\,\,\nu\ =\ 8}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
&\left.\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\sin\pars{\nu x}\ln\pars{\tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x}}
\right\vert_{\ \nu\ \in\ \mathbb{R}_{\ >\ 0}} =
\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{\ic\nu x}\ln\pars{\tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.\Im\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}z^{\nu}\ln\pars{{1 - z^{2} \over 1 + z^{2}}\,\ic}{\dd z \over \ic z}\,
\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}\qquad\pars{~\substack{\ds{z^{\nu}\ \mbox{and}\ \ln\
\mbox{are defined as}}\\[1mm] \ds{Principal\ Branches}}~}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-\,\Re\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}z^{\nu - 1}
\ln\pars{{1 - z^{2} \over 1 + z^{2}}\,\ic}\dd z\,
\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,&
\Re\int_{1}^{0}\pars{\ic y}^{\nu - 1}
\ln\pars{{1 + y^{2} \over 1 - y^{2}}\,\ic}\ic\,\dd y +
\Re\int_{0}^{1}x^{\nu - 1}
\ln\pars{{1 - x^{2} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\ic}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> The integration was performed in a quarter circle in the first quadrant. The 'contributions' from indented paths 'around' $\ds{z = \ic}$ and $\ds{z = 1}$ were omitted because they vanishes out as $\ds{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\left.\bbox[#ffd,10px]{\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\sin\pars{\nu x}\ln\pars{\tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x}}
\right\vert_{\ \nu\ \in\ \mathbb{R}_{\ >\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\Re\int_{0}^{1}\expo{\ic\nu\pi/2}y^{\nu - 1}
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 + y^{2} \over 1 - y^{2}} + \ic\,{\pi \over 2}}\,\dd y +
\Re\int_{0}^{1}x^{\nu - 1}
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - x^{2} \over 1 + x^{2}} + \ic\,{\pi \over 2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\cos\pars{\nu\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}y^{\nu - 1}
\ln\pars{1 + y^{2} \over 1 - y^{2}}\,\dd y +
{\pi \over 2}\sin\pars{\nu\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}y^{\nu - 1}\,\dd y +
\int_{0}^{1}x^{\nu - 1}\ln\pars{1 - x^{2} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
2\cos^{2}\pars{\nu\pi \over 4}
\int_{0}^{1}x^{\nu - 1}\ln\pars{1 - x^{2} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x +
{\pi\sin\pars{\nu\pi/2} \over 2\nu}
\end{align}

> \eqref{1} is reduced to:

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\cos\pars{8x}\ln\pars{\tan\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
2\int_{0}^{1}x^{7}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x^{2} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x +
{\pi^{2} \over 32}
\\[5mm] = &\
4\int_{0}^{1}x^{7}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x -
2\int_{0}^{1}x^{7}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x^{4}}\,\dd x + {\pi^{2} \over 32}
\\[5mm] = &\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{{35 \over 72} - {\pi^{2} \over 24}}}\ -\
{1 \over 8}\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}x\ln\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{1 - {\pi^{2} \over 12}}}\ +\ {\pi^{2} \over 32} =
\bbx{13 \over 36} \approx 0.3611
\end{align}

Comment: nice Felix (+1). We could also use an "infinite rectangle" with short edges $(0,\pi/2)$  and $(i R,i R+\pi/2)$ which seems to be a bit more efficent...